# How to set the default text of a facebook share dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, hashtag

So I have the facebook title in it and description, but how can I set the default `text` for a given share? Basically I'm using just a link `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com`, what I'd like to do is add a `hash tag` as a default text. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the og:description tag. Mark it up like:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Your content goes here">
```

sharer should grab it properly then.

Reference material: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags